# BLDC motor control PCB

Tags: pwm, filter, remote-control, brushless-dc-motor

I am trying to make a PCB to control a Sensorless Brushless motor. I just wanted to know if it looks right. The IC I am using is a TB6588FG it has a 2.5A peak output current. I want to use it with [this](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__6312__hextronik_5gram_brushless_outrunner_2000kv.html) motor. I am going to use a 7.4V battery. The IC needs a analog voltage to change the motor speed. For this I am going to use a first-order RC filter(left side of schematic) to filter the PWM signal. The PWM signal will be supplied by a  microcontroller.

[DATASHEET](http://www.toshiba-components.com/docs/Linear/TB6588FG_en_datasheet.pdf) 
[SCHEMATIC DOWNLOAD](http://www.filedropper.com/bldcdriver)

[image: UPDATED]

Comment: Is there anything specific that you are concerned about?

Comment: I was just wondering if it looks about right? The circuit only needs GND from the MCU which I thought was weird, because how would the IC know the reference voltage.

Comment: I think GND and V- should be joined together. Apart from that your circuit looks good to me.

The reference voltage is 5V, but the analog input range is 1.2~4.1V. You can adjust your PWM ratios to match - eg. if your PWM amplitude is 5V then set the minimum ratio to 24% and maximum to 82%.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Thank you for responding.                        Should I tie the reference voltage from the MCU(5V) to V+(Battery)? The small circuit at the top right corner smooths the 7.4V input for the rest of the circuit. Meaning; V+ is equal to 7.4V and V- is the ground. The circuit has no 5V reference.

Comment: You should keep the MCU's +5V separate. You can power it from the 7.4V battery, but only through a regulator which stabilizes the MCU voltage at +5V. The TB6588FG has an internal +5V reference, but it is only good for a few mA.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Ok thank you. The only thing I don't understand is why the MCU's 5V is not used at all. Also if the Microcontroller and the TB6588FG are running on different power sources the circut will not work right?

Comment: So long as the MPU and TB6588FG grounds are connected together (to provide a common -ve reference point) it will work fine. The TB6588FG doesn't need a 5V supply so there is no reason to connect the MCU's 5V to it.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I was thinking maybe I could tie 5V from the MCU to VR1 in the schematic?

Comment: Don't do that. The TB6588FG has an internal voltage regulator which outputs on VREF. Feeding another 5V supply into VREF could damage the chip.

Comment: @BruceAbbott  I updated the circuit; is it better?